# How to set up flyway default schema in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, flyway

I am checking the Quarkus guide for the flyway extension.

The default schema configuration is not listed and is not supported. I added in my application.properties

```
quarkus.flyway.default-schema=some_schema
quarkus.flyway.defaultSchema=some_schema
```

and tested, but it's not recognised. Is there a workaround or should an issue be created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have opened https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/22957 to address this concern.
If all goes well, this will make it into version `2.7.0.Final`.

Answer (score 1):

got defaulted to

```
quarkus.flyway.default-schema=some_schema
```

just in case anyone is seeing this now

Answer (score 0):

For quarkus version 3 you have to specify flyway and jdbc data source schema separatly.

```
quarkus.flyway.default-schema=<schema_name>
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://<server>:<port>/<DB_name>?currentSchema=<schema_name>
```